# Android LiveData with ArrayAdapter to list view

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-livedata

Hi I was trying to add the live data to my list view data adapter in the main activity, but stuck, Can anyone give me an idea why this doesn't work?

The RecordViewModel:

```
public class RecordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel  {

    private Repository mRepository;

    public static LiveData<List<Record>> mAllRecords;

    public RecordViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new Repository(application);
        mAllRecords = mRepository.getAllRecords();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Record>> getAllWords() {
        mAllRecords=mRepository.getAllRecords();
        return mAllRecords; }
```

The Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
viewModel = new RecordViewModel(getApplication());
//should I use viewModel.getAllWords() to fetch data from database into mAllRecords?
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mAllRecords);
//I am getting error here, can't resolve constructor
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am not clear with the live data convertion to array adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need observer the live data from the record like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
viewModel = new RecordViewModel(getApplication());
//should I use viewModel.getAllWords() to fetch data from database into mAllRecords? yes you should do it on OnCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
viewModel.getAllWords();
final Observer<List<Record>> wordObserve = new Observer<List<Record>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final allRecords List<Record>) {
                // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allRecords);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        };

viewModel.mAllRecords().observe(this, wordObserve);
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, because is very easy if using Kotlin here some   [reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)

Comment: Honestly...Recreating an adapter when data changes?!?!

Comment: Your solution??